# insert in a view of a table in other db

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have a problem with yii2 and I need help:
I have 2 databases in MsSQL db1 and db2, in db2 I have a view to a db1 table. The problem is that when I insert into db2 I can not get the transaction id using $ model-> id or $ model-> getPrimaryKey ().
Does anyone know how to solve this?
this is my model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Documents extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function primaryKey()
    {
        return ['id'];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'documents';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['realname', 'size'], 'required'],
            [['realname'], 'string'],
            [['size'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'realname' => 'Realname',
            'size' => 'Size',
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDocumentSchoolRegistrationToInsurances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentSchoolRegistrationToInsurance::className(), ['document' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDocumentSchoolregistrations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentSchoolregistration::className(), ['document' => 'id']);
    }

}
```

Comment: What  you had tried?

Comment: $model->id and $model->PrimaryKey()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation and revision of the source code of yii2, I realize that after using `save ()` yii only reloads the values of the registry if the primary key is an autoincremental, which in my case will never be fulfilled.
Since it is a View, the solution is to use `Yii :: $ app-> db-> lastInsertID` after using the `save ()` method to get the id generated in the insert.
I think it would be useful to be able to force the newly created registry load.